# Unity Material Glows for no reason

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[Video of my Problem](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jKVrJRuw8IM__5gu3JC5ZvWsmmPAJyr8/view?usp=sharing)

I am making a cooking game and when I mix different ingredients I want the color of the mixture to change, but for some reason the material starts glowing. It only glows when the color is changed through the code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public enum Ingredients
{
    Protein,
    Sodium,
    Fiber,
    Seasons
}

public class MixingBowl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ItemInteraction player;
    public Material mixtureMaterial;
    public Color[] ingredientColors;
    public MeshRenderer renderer;
    public MeshFilter mesh;
    public Mesh[] meshes;
    public List<Ingredients> recipe;

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {
        if (recipe.Count > 0)
        {
            renderer.materials[1] = mixtureMaterial;
        }

        if (recipe.Count < 3)
        {
            if (col.gameObject.name.Contains("Protein"))
            {
                if(player.heldItem == col.gameObject)
                {
                    player.DropItem();
                }
                Destroy(col.gameObject);
                recipe.Add(Ingredients.Protein);
                mixtureMaterial.color += ingredientColors[0];
            }
            if (col.gameObject.name.Contains("Fiber"))
            {
                if (player.heldItem == col.gameObject)
                {
                    player.DropItem();
                }
                Destroy(col.gameObject);
                recipe.Add(Ingredients.Fiber);
                mixtureMaterial.color += ingredientColors[2];
            }
        }

        mesh.mesh = meshes[recipe.Count];
    }
}
```

Comment: Id need to see more but its like somethings emissive..  me? i got a skele whos basically transparent except none of the settings seem to say he should be, but if you can make him come out of his home hes fine..

Comment: Do you have some post processing set up?

Comment: @Nikaas no i dont.